# Bitwise operation on longs

Tags: c#, long-integer, bitwise-operators

I trying to compile this code:

```
Int64 itag = BitConverter.ToInt64(temp, 0);
itag &= 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFC00;
```

However this gives me the following error:

> Operator '&=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'ulong'

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried declaring your itag as a ulong?

Comment: @RoyDictus, This actually solved the problem! I wonder why? the error explicitly states that `&=` won't work on neither `long` nor `ulong`. How is this possible?

Comment: VS2010 compiles and runs the two lines without an itch. What's `somval` ?

Comment: @alex, you're right. Updated question to actual code.

Comment: @AtoMerz - I think the error is stating that you can't bitwsie AND a  long with a ulong.

Comment: It doesn't give me any error in VS2010.

Comment: @AtoMerZ: **NEVER post reminded code. Only _actual codes_, pls.** Because your original question indicated a compiler error and I wasted 10 minutes baking a qualified answer on that already. Thanks.

Comment: @Roy should post an aswer which will be accepted. @AtoMerz, you misunderstood the error message. What it meant is that you can not apply bitwise operators on operands which are of different type. It would successfully apply it to 'long' and 'long' or 'ulong' and 'ulong'. This is because long uses 63 bits to store the number, and the 64th bit goes for the sign. `ulong` however uses all 64 bits to store the number.

Comment: @phresnel, I apologize for the inconvenience. Just so you know I did not intend it: I had changed the literal to the value I had first posted, the error had remained. But when alex said it's ok I recompiled and noticed it's gone (some time VS plays with us) so I posted the value before changing it.

Comment: @AtoMerZ: I see, no offense taken ;)

Comment: @DmitryErokhin: But roy's comment gives fish instead of showing how to fish, i.e. that comment does not prevent future mistakes, so I do not think that comment as is should be accepted.

Comment: @phresnel, I agree, my comment was posted when neither your nor Roy's answer was posted.

Comment: Just got "Operator '>>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'long'". So no, it's not long vs ulong. The quantity shifted by (the right one) must not be too large, it seems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/aa664674%28v=vs.71%29.aspx .

> If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`.

You have

```
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFC00
```

but Int64.Max is:

```
0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

so `long` is not big enough and `ulong` is taken as the type of the literal.

Now you have on the left side a `Int64`, which is signed, and on the right side you have `ulong`, however, there is not overload of `&=` which accepts that combination, which leads to the error.

Answer (score 3):

C# uses the smallest fitting type for integer literals and 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFC00 is too big for long so it's an ulong.

So either convert itag to ulong or 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFC00 to long (unchecked).

Comment: This should have been a comment but it's correct nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Signed and unsigned "numbers" cannot be mix-matched, and Int64 is signed so it's a no-go.

I'd go like this:

```
UInt64 itag = BitConverter.ToUInt64(temp, 0); //note the added 'U' to make it unsigned
itag &= 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFC00; //Now types match, they're both unsigned.
```

Comment: One thing I don't understand, Why is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFC00` considered unsigned? Are are hex literal unsigned in C#?

Comment: As Marcus Meitzler promptly noted in his answer below, the value is too large for a signed type

Answer (score 1):

`itag` is a long. `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFC00` is a ulong. You are trying to mix both in a `&=` statement, which doesn't work.

Why is your literal a ulong? [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674.aspx):

> If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong.

Since the number is too large for int, uint or long, your literal becomes a ulong.

You have two options: Either declare `itag` as a ulong, as others have suggested, or (bitwise) convert your literal into a long:

```
itag &= unchecked((long)0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFC00);
```

This will overflow your ulong into a (negative) long.

Comment: Quoting->If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, **long**, ulong. So long is an option.

Comment: `long` max value is `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, so your literal doesn't fit to `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Section 7.11.1 **Integer logical operators** of the C# Language Specification reads:

> The predefined integer logical operators are:
>
> int operator &(int x, int y);
>
> uint operator &(uint x, uint y);
>
> long operator &(long x, long y);
>
> ulong operator &(ulong x, ulong y);

As you can see, there's no predefined operator between `long` (which is just an alias for `Int64`) and `ulong`, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to `&=` a `long` *and* an `ulong`.

Just replacing the `Int64` with a `ulong` solves the problem because then you are applying `&=` to 2 `ulong`s.