# How to reset single bit in ulong?

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, ulong

I have `ulong` number. I need to be able to quickly set and reset single bit. For example:

**15** is **1111**. By setting 5th bit I will get **47**, so **101111**

I figured it out how to set a bit:

```
ulong a = 15;
a |= 1 << 5; // so, now a=47
```

But I'm struggling how to reset it back to 0. I was trying:

```
a &= ~(1 << 5);
```

It doesn't work, because I can't use `&` operator on `ulong` variable.

What's the workaround? I need this operation to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitwise operation on longs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924762/bitwise-operation-on-longs)

Comment: @itsme86 Although the question that you linked explains what's going on, and would definitely put OP on the right track, it does not provide the work-around that OP is looking for, so I am not sure if it's a good candidate for closing as a duplicate.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I guess it too much to expect the OP to realize that the IDE Error Window message `Operator '&=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ulong' and 'int'` is nearly identical to the [answer proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9925060/2592875) by @
RoyDictus in the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't use & operator on `ulong` variable.

That's because `1` is signed. Making it unsigned with `U` suffix fixes the problem:

```
a &= ~(1U << 5);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/JlIPAZ)